# UseEffect() causing previous values to change

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm new to react/next.js so i just wanted to build a sudoku to get a better understanding. My current problem is getting unique values in the 3x3 fields, currently i have a map for all the fields, it contains the coordinates and its value. But the problem i am facing is that when the next cell gets rendered the values of the previous cells also change all the time, this causes the uniquness needed to fail. The logic determinating the unique numbers should be correct.

This is the main class the board itself, i structured it so that it builds 3x3 fields into a 9x9 for iteration purposes.

```js
export default function Sudoku() {
  const [generatedNumbersMap, setGeneratedNumbersMap] = useState(new Map());

  const addGeneratedNumber = (row: number, col: number, number: number) => {
    setGeneratedNumbersMap((prevMap) => {
      const newMap = new Map(prevMap);
      newMap.set(`${row},${col}`, number);
      return newMap;
    });
  };

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between">
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
        <div className="grid grid-rows-3 border-amber-400">
          {Array.from(Array(3)).map((_, blockRowIndex) => (
            <div key={blockRowIndex} className="flex">
              {Array.from(Array(3)).map((_, blockColIndex) => (
                <div
                  key={`${blockRowIndex}-${blockColIndex}`}
                  className="grid grid-rows-3"
                >
                  {Array.from(Array(3)).map((_, rowIndex) => (
                    <div
                      key={`${blockRowIndex}-${blockColIndex}-${rowIndex}`}
                      className="flex"
                    >
                      {Array.from(Array(3)).map((_, colIndex) => (
                        <Cell
                          key={`${blockRowIndex * 3 + rowIndex}-${
                            blockColIndex * 3 + colIndex
                          }`}
                          row={blockRowIndex * 3 + rowIndex}
                          col={blockColIndex * 3 + colIndex}
                          generatedNumbersMap={generatedNumbersMap}
                          addGeneratedNumber={addGeneratedNumber}
                        />
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

And here in the cell lies the main problem:

```js
interface CellProps {
  row: number;
  col: number;
  generatedNumbersMap: Map<string, number>;
  addGeneratedNumber: (row: number, col: number, number: number) => void;
}

export default function Cell({
  row,
  col,
  generatedNumbersMap,
  addGeneratedNumber,
}: CellProps) {
  // Insert number into cell
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const [possibleNum, setPossibleNum] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
  let revMap = useRef(generatedNumbersMap);
  useEffect(() => {
    let newNum: number = 0;
    const cornerRow: number = Math.floor(row / 3) * 3;
    const cornerCol: number = Math.floor(col / 3) * 3;
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (cornerRow + i === row && cornerCol + j === col) {
          break;
        } else {
          const value = revMap.current.get(`${cornerRow + i}-${cornerCol + j}`);
          console.log(`${row}-${col}: ${value}`);
          if (value !== 0) {
            setPossibleNum(possibleNum.filter((item) => item !== value));
            const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleNum.length);
            newNum = possibleNum[randomIndex];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    setNum(newNum);
    addGeneratedNumber(row, col, newNum);
  }, [row, col]);

  return (
    <div
      className={`${borderClasses} flex items-center justify-center text-lg h-10 w-10`}
    >
      {num}
    </div>
  );
}
```

i tried useRef and various dependency combinations, but i'm probably using the useEffect not correctly. If anybody is willing to help me get a understanding of the problem i would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try it without the effect at all?

Comment: @FoxAmadeus I then get an infinite loop error, but I don't see it. The error points to the setPossibleNum(possibleNum.filter...